# Using Titanium, alloy, I'm trying to make a basic: name password and email field. How would I go about this?

Tags: ios, xml, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am making an app in Titanium. The XML is different from that of Net Beans. for example:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <TextField hintText="Login"></TextField>
        <TextField hintText="Password" passwordMask="true"></TextField>
        <Button>Login</Button>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

this will put the 2 TextField and button all on top of each other... Y?

Comment: it was mentioned that i need to place it in a block or a class of some sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[First take a look at the docs.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_XML_Markup) on how to [style your views](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes). These guides help a lot.

Then try a vertical layout for your window, and more defined sizes for your inputs:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window layout="vertical">
        <TextField hintText="Login" height="40" width="Ti.UI.FILL"></TextField>
        <TextField hintText="Password" passwordMask="true" height="40" width="Ti.UI.FILL"></TextField>
        <Button height="40" width="Ti.UI.FILL">Login</Button>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

That should get you started.